# rails test を実行したところ'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "モデル名_pkey"'　のエラーが出ました

Tags: ruby-on-rails

現在Userモデルに対して以下のようなテストを実行しています。

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
end
```

Userモデル

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

rails test を実行したところ
`duplicate key value violates unique constraint "movies_pkey"`　
のエラーが出ました。

以下の記事を参考にrails consoleにて

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |t|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(t)
end
```

を実行したのですが同じエラーコードが出てしまいます。
https://qiita.com/YutoYasunaga/items/a89805441d6961ef658a

どのようにすればエラーを修正できるでしょうか？

エラー全文

```
Error:
UserTest#test_name_should_be_present:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "movies_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(980190962) already exists.

    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:47:in `exec'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:46:in `block in execute'    
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:696:in `block (2 levels) in log'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'        
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:695:in `block in log'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:687:in `log'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:45:in `execute'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:129:in `execute_batch'      
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:413:in `block (3 levels) in insert_fixtures_set'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `block in transaction' 
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'        
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `transaction'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:412:in `block (2 levels) in insert_fixtures_set'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/referential_integrity.rb:19:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:411:in `block in insert_fixtures_set'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:523:in `with_multi_statements'    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:410:in `insert_fixtures_set'  
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:638:in `block in insert'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:629:in `each'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:629:in `insert'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:615:in `read_and_insert'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:567:in `create_fixtures'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:268:in `load_fixtures'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:122:in `setup_fixtures'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:10:in `before_setup'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:40:in `before_setup'

rails test test/models/user_test.rb:13

.

Finished in 0.139483s, 14.3386 runs/s, 7.1693 assertions/s.
2 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 1):

解決いたしました。

fixturesの中のymlファイルのコードを削除することでエラーを解決することができました。
お騒がせ致しました。